# YII form get closed immediately after it start, can't place any elements inside that

Tags: yii

when i add a form inside the for loop , the form get closed immediately and the elements are placed out side the form

i need to get the form with particular elements inside that
this is my code

```
`<?php
 for($i=0;$i<$s;$i++)
     {?>
      <div>
        <?php
        echo CHtml::form('', 'post', array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')); 
        ?>   
    <input type='text'>
    <?php
     echo CHtml::endForm(); 
         ?>
      </div>
   <?php } ?>`
```

and the out put of the code shows

```
    <div>
<form method="post" action="/blogs/index.php?r=site/search" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
<input type="text">
</div>
```

Can someone please help me to solve this issue, ...
thanks

Comment: Which version of Yii are you using?  I just copied and pasted your code into my Yii application and couldn't reproduce your problem... I am using Yii v1.1.7